# Viewport Meta: Prevent pinching past 0% but keep scaleable

Tags: javascript, ios, css, cordova, meta

I am building a Cordova app that I want to keep user scaleable behaviour. However, On iOS, if I pinch to zoom beyond the original scale, iOS Webview adds this elastic, bounce effect.

I want to prevent this behaviour, so that when the scales back down to its original size, it stops dead and removes this 'bounce'.

Here is the meta I'm using:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=yes, width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=2.5">
```

I want to keep the natural pinch/zoom/pan behaviour, but prevent the bounce.

Here is an [image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJ2QJ.png) of what is happening past scale.

I've experimented with watching changes on `screen.deviceXDPI` to then prevent any further scrolling to no avail.

I feel I am missing something simple.